# table scroll css change from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I've a table where I need to set a `max-height` and make it scrollable.

**My Table design**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-notactiveusers table-custom-scroll" style="border: 1px solid #e7eaec;" id="tblNonUandMeUsersList" runat="server">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="width: 5%">#</th>
         <th style="width: 33%">First Name</th>
         <th style="width: 30%">Country Code</th>
         <th style="width: 32%">Mobile Number</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**My Table css :**

```
.table-custom-scroll > thead, .table-custom-scroll > tbody {
    display: block;
}

.table-custom-scroll > tbody {
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But, if the table has less rows than the max height, there is a space for the body on the right side like shown in the image[image: Image with Space in the right side]

So,I thought of changing the css to `display : compact`, if the table rows are less than 12.

**My JS to change css**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var notactiverowCount = $('.table-notactiveusers tr').length;

      if (notactiverowCount < 12) {
         $('.table-notactiveusers > thead').css('display', 'compact');
         $('.table-notactiveusers > body').css('display', 'compact');
     }
    if (notactiverowCount < 12) {
        $('.table-notactiveusers').children('head').css('display', 'compact');
        $('.table-notactiveusers').children('body').css('display', 'compact');
    }
});
</script>
```

But the css is not changing. Can anyone tell me the mistake I was doing?

Comment: try putting an !important after compact in your jquery statement ..

Comment: The Css has been defined on .table-custom-scroll, so i thought that must be overriding the style property..

Answer (score 0):

what about using only css

```
.table-custom-scroll{
    display: block;
}
```

see demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/behgvyut/1/)